# Search results are limited, no good results return when searching for more than one word

Tags: php, mysql, search

Just to make it easy to understand: in the table "result" there is a column called "result_search". one of the lines is for example: "word letter sentence".

My search works great if I search for any of those word or even if I search for "word letter" or "letter sentence", but as I mix it up and search for "sentence word" or "letter word" no results are shown.

How do I fix this? I would assume I need to tell the search engine to search for every word by itself  and return only the results where both words are present, but neccessarily next to each other like they are in the table?!
Here is what I have:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>


<?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];          
    $min_length = 3;         
    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);             
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM result WHERE (`result_search` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());               

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){                 
                echo "<p><h3>".$results['result_search']."</h3></p>";
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can split your keyword by space and then search for all possible single words using OR

Comment: Nice overview of the options... http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with how the LIKE operator works …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM result WHERE (`result_search` REGEXP '(".preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', $query).")')") or die(mysql_error());
```

`preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', $query)` replaces white spaces with `|` to search for every single word in an `OR` condition.

The resulting query will be

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE (`result_search` REGEXP '(word|letter)')
```

the query result will be every racord containing 'word' or 'better'

To get records containing both string REGEX can't be used because of 'repetition-operator operand invalid' error using `(?=.*` for an `AND` condition

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE 1";
$matches = preg_split('/\s+/',$query);
foreach($matches as $match){
$sql .= " AND `result_search` LIKE '%".$match."%'";
}
$raw_results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

`$matches = preg_split('/\s+/',$query);` splits where it finds spaces.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of what this accomplishes instead of just posting one line of code? Especially when using regular expressions this is not really trivial.